# Which methods of the String class to use to get string after a white space?

Tags: java, string, methods

I started a java course a few weeks ago and today we were given a question sheet we will be doing in class tomorrow. I wanted to have a go at it myself tonight but alas I'm stuck on question 1.

We covered methods of the `String` class today but I can't figure out which if any of them to use.

So finally here's the question:

> Q. Write and test a program which will prompt the user to enter their name and write to the screen just the surname. (Where the surname is interpreted as everything after the first white space)

And here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fullName;
        String surname;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        fullName = keyboard.nextLine();

        if(fullName.contains(" ")) {
            // not sure what goes in here?
        }

    }

}
```

I've been messing around with the if statement above and also various methods of the String class like `subString()`, `charAt()` etc but I don't know how to find the first space and then print out the String after the first space.

Comment: `String#substring` will work here. Also, use `String#indexOf(' ')`. Yes, you can use several methods of the same class in the same line.

Comment: Look at the API (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) it has a good example of how to substring something (and given the example from @Eran, you can find the index to start the substring)

Comment: +1 for a well formatted first question!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and help. Yeah that makes sense to do it that way, I will mess around with it now and hopefully get it to run :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by making use of indexOf() and subString() methods of String class: For e.g.,

```
    public String substringAfter(String str) {
        int pos = str.indexOf(" ");
        if (pos == -1) {
            return "";
        }
        return str.substring(pos + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use what's in the comments, but you could use the split method too. It takes two parameters (or one, the second one is optional): the delimeter String and the limit. It returns the String array of splitted Strings. Example:

```
String[] splitted = fullName.split(" ", 2);
```

Now splitted[0] is the first name (part before first white space) and splitted[1] is the rest.

More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

And in general you can find a lot in the Java API documentation.

**UPDATE**

1) I mistaked the limit, it should be 2 instead of 1

For clarification, here is the test:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String fullName = "Luiggi SecondName ThirdName NotMyLastNameYet StillNotMyLastNameCuzImaTroll";
        String surname;

        String[] splitted = fullName.split(" ", 2);
        surname = splitted[1];

        System.out.println(splitted[1]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
SecondName ThirdName NotMyLastNameYet StillNotMyLastNameCuzImaTroll
```

Comment: I would not suggest using `String#split` because that would mean explaining regex for more complex scenarios. Also, what would happen if user inputs *Luiggi SecondName ThirdName NotMyLastNameYet StillNotMyLastNameCuzImaTroll*?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: He said that surname is everything after the first white space

Comment: And your answer doesn't cover the rest of the elements in the array after index 0, you state that `splitted[1]` is the only surname, but with the input I provide in my comment, your answer is wrong.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza read the question please, he stated that surname is everything after the first white space, which is why I chose this answer

Comment: And **read my comment** where I provide **an example that breaks your current answer**.

Comment: But your post doesn't cover the exact answer OP needs... So, this answer is **wrong**.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes OP stated that `(Where the surname is interpreted as everything after the first white space)` and according to that this answer does make sense. I don't think this is wrong with the requirements given. And YEs I am agree about `regex` part.

Comment: Again. User input: *Luiggi SecondName ThirdName NotMyLastNameYet StillNotMyLastNameCuzImaTroll*. Your current code: `System.out.println(splitted[1]);` Output: *SecondName*. Expected output: *SecondName ThirdName NotMyLastNameYet StillNotMyLastNameCuzImaTroll*. Your answer is **wrong**.

Comment: From the question: *Where the surname is interpreted **as everything after the first white space***. Again, your answer doesn't cover that. I cannot read anything related to lastname in this question.

Comment: I would not call it wrong but perhaps incomplete for certain inputs.  What I think @LuiggiMendoza is getting at is that in the input he gave as an example, the output of `splitted[1]` is not **everything** after the first space - instead, it's only the **first item** after the first space

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: **Write and test a program which will prompt the user to enter their name and write to the screen just the surname. (Where the surname is interpreted as everything after the first white space)** so if the surname is everything after the first white space, then everything after Luiggi (as in your example) should be outputted and that is what it does

Comment: No, it doesn't. Try it yourself.

Comment: @blurfus it doesn't, read the documentation, and I wasn't going for the general case, but for this exact scenario as I stated

Comment: @StealthyHunter7 I did, and you are correct - I stand corrected

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you or do you **only** want `String` methods?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fullName;
        String surname;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        fullName = keyboard.nextLine();

        if(fullName.contains(" ")) {
            Scanner nameScanner = new Scanner(fullName);
            String name = nameScanner.next();
            surname = nameScanner.nextLine();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I messed around with String methods and came up with this  String fullName;
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
  fullName = keyboard.nextLine();
  
  int i = fullName.indexOf(' ');
  String s1 = fullName.substring(i);
  
  System.out.println("Surname is " + s1);

Comment: okay that didn't paste my code like I thought it would :-( hopefully it kinda makes sense